# Finding Average of One Column Based on 2 Other Columns RStudio

Tags: r, group-by, rstudio, aggregate, mean

I currently have a data frame that has three columns (City, State and Income) I wrote an example of the data below...

```
City     State     Income 
Addison  Illinois   71,000
Addison  Illinois   101,000
Addison  Illinois   81,000
Addison  Texas      74,000
```

As you can see there are repeats of the cities. There are several Addison, IL's because income differs by the zip-code/area of the city.

I want to take the average of all incomes in a given city and state. In this example I want the average of all Addison IL's but NOT including Addison, Texas.

I am looking for this (in this given example)

```
City    State    MeanIncome
Addison Illinois  84,333
Addison Texas     74,000
```

I tried this:

```
Income_By_City <- aggregate( Income ~ City, df, mean )
```

But it gave me the average of ALL Addison's, including Texas...

**Is there a way to take the average of Income Column, based on City AND State??**

I am pretty new to coding, so I'm not sure if this is a simple question. But I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 3):

```
df <- data.frame(City = c("Addison", "Addison", "Addison", "Addison"), State = c("Illinois", "Illinois", "Illinois", "Texas"), Income = c(71000, 101000, 81000, 74000))

library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(City, State) %>%
   summarise(MeanIncome=(mean(Income)))


#     City     State   MeanIncome
#1 Addison  Illinois   84333.33
#2 Addison     Texas   74000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~City,      ~State,      ~Income, 
"Addison",  "Illinois",  71000,
"Addison",  "Illinois",  101000,
"Addison",  "Illinois",  81000,
"Addison",  "Texas",     74000
)

df %>% 
  group_by(City, State) %>% 
  mutate(AverageIncome = mean(Income))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   City, State [2]
     City    State Income AverageIncome
    <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Addison Illinois  71000      84333.33
2 Addison Illinois 101000      84333.33
3 Addison Illinois  81000      84333.33
4 Addison    Texas  74000      74000.00
```